# How to make the checkbox in the listview readonly c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, checkbox

When I set the `ListView.Enabled` property to `false`, the scrollbar will not work.

All I want is when the user decides to add products, the checkbox will work as normally as it should same goes for the scrollbar on the `ListView` but when the user wants to view the products, it is scrollable on the `ListView` but it won't let the user check or uncheck the checkboxes. Please help me.

When I add the products I can scroll and check the checkboxes as
normal:

```
private void addProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listviewProduct.Enabled = true;
}
```

When I view the products the I cannot scrolldown and I cannot check the checkboxes too (grayed out):

```
private void viewProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listviewProduct.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Is this Winforms or WPF?

Comment: Could you perhaps add code that describes your problem in more detail, or maybe some screenshot of the program which shows the issue that you are having?

Comment: Have you tried setting `enabled = false` on the checkboxes instead?

Comment: this is in winforms sorry please don't go thumbs down. :(

Comment: how do I control the checkbox on the listview itself?

Comment: The downvotes are because the question is unclear. There is very little to work with in your question as it lacks a lot of information. Add information and there will be less/no downvotes. How you control the checkboxes is impossible to say, because you haven't provided any information on how you create them. Since there are multiple ways to create controls in a winforms application, you have to give us more information in order for anyone to help you further. How do you create your application?

Comment: Okay I'm sorry I'm just newbie here. I will edit my post thanks alot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily implement this with the ItemCheck event.  Say you have a bool variable in your form class that indicates that the ListView is in "view only" mode:

```
    private bool ViewReadOnly;
```

Then write the ItemCheck event handler like this:

```
    private void listViewProduct_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
        if (ViewReadOnly) e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
    }
```

Simply set the variable to *true* when your UI switches to the "view only" mode, back to *false* when it switches into edit mode.  So:

```
    private void viewProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ViewReadOnly = true;
        listViewProduct.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
    }
```

Etcetera.  Don't skimp on the BackColor change, or whatever other indication you prefer, you want to give the user some feedback that banging on the checkbox isn't going to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can use set Checkboxed to `false` when in Read Only mode?

```
listView1.CheckBoxes = false;
```

That way they won't even see them. And it avoids confusion to the user (if I see a checkbox on a control, then I usually expect I can do something with it).